# MySQL Async - How i can use it?

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous

i try to run my own TCP application, now i will be Check if a user is exit.

My question is: How can i use mySQL Async?

```
        public static bool CheckUserLogin(string Username,string Password){
        try{
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)){ return false; }
            if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Username, "^[a-zA-Z0-9\x20]+$")) { return false; }
            if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Password, "^[a-zA-Z0-9\x20]+$")) { return false; }
            bool UserExit = false;
            DataBase_Connection.DB_Conn.OpenAsync();
            try{
                string c_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `KoN_Account` WHERE BINARY `AccountName` = @U_Name AND `HashPass` = @P_Pass LIMIT 1;";
                using (MySqlCommand CU_cmd = new MySqlCommand(c_query, db_Conn)){
                    CU_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@U_Name", Username);
                    CU_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_Pass", Password);
                    var count = CU_cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    UserExit = Convert.ToBoolean(count);
                }
            }
            catch{
            }
            DataBase_Connection.DB_Conn.CloseAsync();
            return UserExit;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            LoginConsole.WriteConsoleLoginParams(System.ConsoleColor.Red, "ERROR CheckUserLogin", ex.ToString() + "\nFailed to connect to the database (server shutdown...)");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

My question is it it right what i make? With **OpenAsync** and **CloseAsync** ?

Also how can i use: ExecuteScalar in Async way?

Thanks for your help

Comment: why would you perform an async login? what else could a non-validated user do?

Comment: Its for a TCP Server. So much user will connect to him.

Comment: This is a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70111).

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `async` version you will need to change your method from returning a `bool` to returning a `Task<bool>` and add the `async` modifier, then you will want to use the `Async` suffixed methods and `await` them.

I would also do the `DB_Conn.CloseAsync()` in a `finally` block, and remove the empty catch as you already have some form of basic error handling.

Please note you can only use `await` in `catch` and `finally` when using C#6 and up.

So you example would look like:

```
public static async Task<bool> CheckUserLogin(string Username, string Password)
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)) { return false; }
        if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Username, "^[a-zA-Z0-9\x20]+$")) { return false; }
        if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Password, "^[a-zA-Z0-9\x20]+$")) { return false; }
        bool UserExit = false;
        await DataBase_Connection.DB_Conn.OpenAsync();
        try
        {
            string c_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `KoN_Account` WHERE BINARY `AccountName` = @U_Name AND `HashPass` = @P_Pass LIMIT 1;";
            using (MySqlCommand CU_cmd = new MySqlCommand(c_query, db_Conn))
            {
                CU_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@U_Name", Username);
                CU_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P_Pass", Password);
                var count = await CU_cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
                UserExit = Convert.ToBoolean(count);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            await DataBase_Connection.DB_Conn.CloseAsync();
        }
        return UserExit;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LoginConsole.WriteConsoleLoginParams(System.ConsoleColor.Red, "ERROR CheckUserLogin", ex.ToString() + "\nFailed to connect to the database (server shutdown...)");
    }
    return false;
}
```